# Search hidden and visible directories in the same command

Tags: powershell

I need to get **hidden** and **visible** directories that match certain criteria and I'd like to do it in the same call, instead of repeating the search for hidden and for visible items. Apparently this is not possible with `GetChildItem`, using the `-Attribute` or the `-Hidden` parameters.

I cannot get the `-Attribute` parameter to work the way I want:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Attributes Hidden+!Hidden -Path $this.searchPath | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_.Name -eq $targetFeatureToSearch)
            {
                $result.Add([IO.Directory]::GetParent($_.FullName).FullName);
            }
        }
```

And if I use `-Hidden`, only hidden items are included in the search. If not used, only visible items are included in the search.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path $this.searchPath | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_.Name -eq $targetFeatureToSearch)
            {
                $result.Add([IO.Directory]::GetParent($_.FullName).FullName);
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to combine both searches, for **performance** reasons?

Comment: Use the `-Force` parameter with `Get-ChildItem`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want `Get-ChildItem` to show you both visible and hidden items, you have to `-Force` it to, as @LotPings comments.

But if you want to do anything `for performance reasons?`, `Get-ChildItem` probably is not a good approach.

```
robocopy $this.searchPath $this.searchPath /E /L /FP /NS /NC /NJH /NJS
```

Will spit out a list of full names, as text, very quickly. The options mean:

- source and "destination", but it's not going to copy or move anything
- /E - recurse including empty directories
- /L - list files and folders only, don't do any copying or moving
- /FP - show full paths of files and folders
- /NS /NC - no size, no 'class' (file vs directory) indicator in the output
- /NJH /NJS - no job header or summary, just a plain list of content

and it does include hidden things too.

[Edit: TheIncorrigible1 comments that `$this` is an automatic variable for class methods to refer to the current instance, and if you're using it in PowerShell functions, that's a bad practise. I won't edit the above code, in case you actually are using it in a method, and so my code looks like yours.]

Comment: I'd like to point out `$this` is an automatic variable and unless this is a class method, it is harmful to use.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 good catch! OP might be doing that, so I won't edit the code, but I've edited in your warning.

Comment: I'm using it within a class, so the $this is right, AFAIK.

Comment: Now, re-reading the official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) I found the that the -Force option will do... I didn't notice the other day. Thank you guys!